# How to avoid Request Entity Too Large 413 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to avoid this 413 error ?

> Request Entity Too Large
>
> The requested resource /serverpath/reports.php does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
>
> Apache Server at demo3.website_name Port 80

So, could any one please help to set php.ini and how to set htaccess to allow overwrite status

Answer (score 84):

**How to fix it in NGINX? client_max_body_size**

To fix this, you need to increase the value of the client_max_body_size directive. This directive defines the maximum amount of data Nginx will accept in an HTTP request. By default this value is set to 1 megabyte, meaning if you attempt to upload a file larger than 1 megabyte you'll be getting an Error 413: Request entity too large page. You can insert this directive at three levels:

- In the http block: this will set the directive value for all server and locations in your configurationn
- In the server block: this will set the directive value for all locations of one particular server
- In the location block: this will set the directive value for one specific location in a particular server

In this example I'm going to insert it in my http block and set it to 500 megabytes:

```
http {

    client_max_body_size 500M; # allows file uploads up to 500 megabytes
    [...]
}
```

source:
http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com.ar/2013/09/nginx-error-413-request-entity-too-large.html

Comment: seems like this not so much per file as it is per upload session? I had mine set to 500m but got this error after uploading 1000 4 mb files via fineuploader.

Comment: omg, this worked every time i used it, please check if your config is being applied (and restart nginx also).

Comment: Check using this command line:
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -T

Comment: *"In the location block: this will set the directive value for one specific location in a particular server"*... this didn't work for me for some reason. I had to set it in the server block.

Comment: I put it in conf file it worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to look for the following line in the `php.ini` and set it to the size that you require:

```
post_max_size = 25M
```

You can then set it in the `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value post_max_size 25M
```

Comment: Are you running it locally or from a hosted domain? Some service provider do not allow changing the php.ini and it might require permissions to change the .htaccess file.

Comment: hosted domain i can't access php.ini file

Answer (score 2):

On Apache 2.4 it is worth looking at the `LimitRequestBody` directive as well. It can be configured per vhost and it goes into the `<Directory>` section.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  [...]
  <Directory "/var/www/public_html"> 
    [...]
    LimitRequestBody 33554432 
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

The size value is in bytes. This finally solved it for me when I tried both the `php.ini` max size directives and was still getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

I was uploading files large files from react-native application, it was throwing mentioned error. I just added **client_max_body_size** in **location**
directive in ngnix config and it started working.

ngnix config path - /etc/ngnix/sites-available and file name is **default**

```
server {
   listen         80 default_server;
   listen         [::]:80 default_server;
   root           /var/www/html;

charset utf-8;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3015;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       client_max_body_size 500M; //<<=== HERE IT IS
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`php.ini` has a setting called `post_max_size`, which is set to 8M by default (on Ubuntu at least).

Consider increasing that value if you are posting a lot of data.

Comment: yes, i can set post_max_size in php or htaccess but i can't access for php.ini file when i setup this on php file its not working

Comment: Did you try to restart the webserver after changing the value in `php.ini` ?

Answer (score -1):

client_max_body_size 500M; Its working for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer has been provided already. Please only add a new answer if it provides a useful new information