# Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large) in ultracart

Tags: php, api

I m using Ultracart checkout api.
I find the issue when I run item.html on server. 
http://www.cfdevshop.com/rest_api/item.html

I have changed merchant id and itemId what we have.
It is running on local but throws an error on server as 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121227/how-to-avoid-request-entity-too-large-413-error

Comment: Thanks Damith, I have tried suggested anwser but did not work.