# AJAX calls inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

So, I have a list of data that I am out putting onto my view, and each list item has an id.

Each of these list items is a bar and I have a document created for each bar that at least one user is going to. For those bars where no users are going, there is no document created.

I need to make an AJAX call for each list item to the database to check

i) If a document exists for that list item
ii) If a document exists, how many users are going according to the document.

I attempted a solution using a while loop, where the update for the while loop was contained in the callback for the AJAX call. Here is the code

```
function updateAllGoingButtons(){
    var i = 0;
    var dataToPass = {};
    var numButtons = global_data_object.listData.businesses.length;
    while(i < numButtons){
        dataToPass.button = global_data_object.listData.businesses[i].id;
        dataToPass = JSON.stringify(dataToPass);
        ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', '/update-buttons', dataToPass, function(data){
            console.log(i);
            i++;
        }));
    }
}
```

When I attempted to run the function, I got  the error,

> Request entity too large

So, is there a better way to go about doing what I am trying to do? Should I use promises? Or is there simply an error in the way I am trying to make the AJAX call from within a while loop?

For reference, here is the ajaxRequest function

```
'use strict';

var appUrl = window.location.origin;
var ajaxFunctions = {
   ready: function ready (fn) {
      if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
         return;
      }

      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
         return fn();
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
   },
   ajaxRequest: function ajaxRequest (method, url, data, callback) {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.response);
         }
      };

      xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      xmlhttp.send(data);
   }
};
```

Comment: yes consider using promises...Promises are always the best way to deal with ajax calls

Comment: the error you are getting `Request entity too large` is no where connected with your `while` loop. It will come even though you go with other mechanism.

Comment: @vijayP - So even if I use the async library, I will still get the same error?

Comment: I believe so. The error is related to the upload size. Please check the associated configurations first.

Comment: @vijayP - Sorry what do you mean check the associated configurations first?

Comment: @vijayP - So there doesn't seem to be a limit to the POST data size in HTTP requests in JavaScript.

Comment: This may help you to resolve this error: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121227/how-to-avoid-request-entity-too-large-413-error

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the npm library called async, it has an each method that you can do asynchronous calls within. If you use promises, the Promise.all method in Bluebird could be very useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's how I did the multiple AJAX calls from within a loop. I used this resource https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f#.d7ymg99mp (Great resource!)

Here's the code

```
$('.btn-group').find('button').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        dataToPass.button = $(this).attr('id');
        var ajax = $.ajax({
            url: '/update-buttons',
            method: 'post',
            data: dataToPass,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Essentially, what this does is selects a div with the class 'btn-group' and then iterates over each button within that div using the jQuery each operator. Then simply make an AJAX request and use the success chain callback to access the returned data.