# Ajax request with formdata returns error 'request entity too large'

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload

I'm trying to send form with files using FormData and in desktop modern browsers it works fine, but in mobiles my code returns error 'request entity too large'.
I've tested on iphone 5s (iOS 11) Safari and on android Firefox.

There is the code:

```
window.xhrJson = function (url, method, data, customParams) {
    return xhr(url, method, 'JSON', data, customParams);
};
window.xhr = function (url, method, dataType, data, customParams) {
    var params = {
        url: url,
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        method: method,
        dataType: dataType
    };
    if (typeof data !== 'undefined') {
        params.data = data;
    }
    if (typeof customParams !== 'undefined') {
        params = mergeOptions(params, customParams);
    }
    return $.ajax(params);
};
window.mergeOptions = function(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
};

// Main function to upload form with files
window.upload = function ($form, url) {
    var xhr = xhrJson(url, 'POST', new FormData($form[0]), {
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    xhr.fail(function (data, status, err) {
        alert(err);
    }).done(function (data) {

    });
    return xhr;
};
```

Comment: Has to do with your server settings, nothing to do with Ajax. You are sending a file size greater than your server will allow.

Comment: I've changed all possible settings on server. And as i said on desktop it works fine, i sent image 70Mb size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121227/how-to-avoid-request-entity-too-large-413-error

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. My phone used local proxy server which was't properly configured.