# How to send a base64 encoded pdf file in php?

Tags: php, json, base64

I am using a third party app to send and receive whats app messages and files. I have been facing trouble sending a pdf file, so i decided to send it via base64 encoding. my file is a 70 kbs and I am still getting this error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://eu4.chat-api.com/INSTANCE
>   ID/sendFile?TOKEN): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 413 Payload Too Large in

My code looks like this:

````
$image = chunk_split("data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiWhs8XX...");
$to = "";
$filename = "menu.pdf";
$caption = "menu";
$data = [
'phone' => $to,
'filename' => $filename,
'body' => $image,
'caption' => $caption
];
$json = json_encode($data);
$url = 'https://eu4.chat-api.com/INSTANCE ID/sendFile?TOKEN';
$options = stream_context_create(['http' => [
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
    'content' => $json
]
]);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $options); ```
````

I don't understand where the code is wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Request Entity Too Large 413 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121227/how-to-avoid-request-entity-too-large-413-error)